# JavaScript: create a sequence for each unique value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have an array of objects and I want to create a sequence based on each value. For example take the array:

```
let starting_data = [
  {str: "a"},
  {str: "a"},
  {str: "b"},
  {str: "c"},
  {str: "a"},
  {str: "c"},
  {str: "a"},
  {str: "b"}
]
```

I know I can use a map and reduce to find the unique number of each `str` value

```
let uniques = starting_data.map(function(value) {return value.str;}).reduce((acc, val) => {
      acc[val] = acc[val] === undefined ? 1 : acc[val] += 1;
      return acc;
}, {})
```

But I'm not sure how to leverage this to eventually get what I want as my desired output:

```
let desired_output = [
  {str: "a", count: 1},
  {str: "a", count: 2},
  {str: "b", count: 1},
  {str: "c", count: 1},
  {str: "a", count: 3},
  {str: "c", count: 2},
  {str: "a", count: 4},
  {str: "b", count: 2}
]
```

Where the counts start over for each unique value, but the `a`s go to 4, and `b` and `c` go to 2. I tried messing with `arr.sort` if I need to do that first but I wasn't sure how to sort based on a value inside an object... Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned it you want it to be purely functional, so here it is.

```js
let starting_data = [
  { str: "a" },
  { str: "a" },
  { str: "b" },
  { str: "c" },
  { str: "a" },
  { str: "c" },
  { str: "a" },
  { str: "b" },
];

const uniqueCount = starting_data
  .reduce(
    (arr, { str }) => {
      const hash = arr[0];
      hash[str] ||= 0;
      arr.push({ str, count: ++hash[str] });
      return arr;
    },
    [{}]
  )
  .slice(1);

console.log(uniqueCount);
```

This prints:

```
[
  { str: 'a', count: 1 },
  { str: 'a', count: 2 },
  { str: 'b', count: 1 },
  { str: 'c', count: 1 },
  { str: 'a', count: 3 },
  { str: 'c', count: 2 },
  { str: 'a', count: 4 },
  { str: 'b', count: 2 }
]
```

### How it works

This solution keeps a hash as the first element of the array being built by `reduce`.

1. The array starts as `[{}]`.
2. Populate the hash key with a `0` if the key doesn't already exist.
3. Push a new element to the array with `str` and a `count`.
4. `hash[str]` is incremented by 1 and then used as the value.

The array now looks like:

```
[{ a: 1 }, { str: "a", count: 1 }]
```

5. We continue this until we've iterated through every item.

```
[ { a: 2 }, { str: 'a', count: 1 }, { str: 'a', count: 2 } ]
[ { a: 2, b: 1 }, { str: 'a', count: 1 }, { str: 'a', count: 2 }, { str: 'b', count: 1 } ]
// Continues until it finishes
```

6. At the end, we remove this initial hash by slicing the array onwards from the first element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

can do something like keeping a seperate object to keep track of the counts

```js
let starting_data = [
  {str: "a"},
  {str: "a"},
  {str: "b"},
  {str: "c"},
  {str: "a"},
  {str: "c"},
  {str: "a"},
  {str: "b"}
]


let counts = {};
let res = starting_data.map(({str}) => {
    if(!counts[str])counts[str]=0;
  counts[str]+=1
  return {str,count:counts[str]}
})

console.log(res)
```